# Pandas: How to set an index without sorting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df I wish to sort by two columns (say, `by=['Cost','Producttype']`) and set the index to be on a different column (`df.what_if_cost.abs()`)

I am new to Python, so originally I sorted the df twice, where in the second time I kept the original index. It is too inefficient, even when doing it `inplace`. I tried stuff like `set_index` and `reset_index` but to no avail. Ideally, as described, I wish the output df to be sorted by two columns, but indexed by a different third column.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample of your dataframe and ideally the expected output

Comment: You say: 'originally I sorted the df twice, where in the second time I kept the original index.'. I think this is the right solution to your problem, I do not think you can do better than that